# Is it the right way to use a namespace or global object for data source instead of using props or state?

Tags: reactjs

I've started digging the habitat of reactjs and found out that there is no binding of scopes to views like AngularJS has. As I understand for rerendering you should trigger render function *mainly* with changing the state by calling `setState`.

If you have a DOM hierarchy based on your data structure, you could use State Lifting for modifying the data that used by upper levels of your component tree.

My questions are

1. Am I right on aforementioned statements?
2. Is it correct in the sense of best practices of reactjs to use a global object (lets call it the resource object) that holds the data and  controls the rerendering by calling components ***change observer*** functions like below;

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/AttilaSATAN/pen/KBaZOY)

Answer (score 1):

2. You can use redux for the kinds of data which can be modified by many components. You don't you do that like you did by defining a global object. Redux is a very cool library which solves the problem you are facing. You can call it a central/global state manager. if you need to change/get something from the global state you call redux function and you get your data.